# First Order Logic to CNF

Tags: first-order-logic, conjunctive-normal-form

> There is a Bear. The Bear either sleeps in its cave or hunts in the forest. If the
>   Bear is hungry then it does not sleep. If the Bear is tired then it does not hunt.

**Question
A**

Formulate the story, above, in FOPC, using your predicates and/or objects.

**Attempt A**

```
SleepsInCave(Bear) v HuntsInForest(Bear)
Hungry(Bear) -> ~SleepsInCave(Bear)
Tired(bear) -> ~HuntsInForest(Bear)
```

**Question B**

Convert your FOPC into conjunctive normal form

**Attempt B**

Not sure how to conver to CNF because I was unable to complete part A!